# JavaScript can' get appendChild to work

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

I'm trying to append a link to my html-document. It works in JSFiddle but not with a html-document and js-file. Can anyone please se what I'm doing wrong.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2LcRF/

HTML-code:
    
    
    
    Javascript Hidden textarea

```
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
    <p>hello</p>


    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript-code;

```
var test= document.getElementById("content");
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "#"
var text = document.createTextNode("länk");
a.appendChild(text);
test.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: Make sure DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of creating a text node? Just set the innerHTML.

```
var test= document.getElementById("content");
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "#"
a.innerHTML = "länk";
test.appendChild(a);
```

Also, where is the script tag? If you're not using a `window.onload` listener, the script tag should be added as the last item in `body`

Comment: I have a script tag but it seems to be something wrong with the last line of js code.